# What do I need to properly implement a single sign-on with a legacy authentication rest API?

Tags: java, php, ruby-on-rails, authentication, kohana

**overview**
I have a legacy php system that is used for user management and authentication. It has a restful api to authenticate users. I say legacy because I do not believe the API adheres to modern standards and does not have proper documentation. 
From the documentation left

> ...It (the API) can issues cookies, etc. Fields username, context, and password are
>   required. setcookies is not required. The default value is TRUE, that
>   is if setcookies is not explicitly set to false than cookies will be
>   set.
>
> Response: HTTP 200 on success, 404 on failure.
>
> Example request:
>
> ```
>  <logins> <login> <username>[username/email]</username>
>  <context>[context]</context> <password>[password, unhashed]</password>
>  <setcookies>[TRUE / FALSE]</setcookies> </login> </logins>
> ```

**What I need:**
I have a few sites, site A and site B that live under the same top level domain. I need to be able to automatically logs users in site B when they login Site A and log users out in a similar manner.

**Details**
At the moment, Site A works with the legacy API to sign the users in and it does it successfully. However, I am unable to detect that on Site B. 
My questions are

1. What would should I be looking for in ideal situation? Perhaps a shared authentication cookie that should be shared?
2. What data should the authentication cookie contain?
3. And lastly how do I check if the user logged out on site B? should the cookie values change or I have make frequent service calls to verify the user is still logged in or logged out?

Comment: Many things depend on the specifics of your site, but a shared cookie may do it, as you mention they share the same top domain, setting the domain to something like ".mydomain.com" should do it.

Comment: Yes. I know that but What exactly do I do with the cookie info? What happens to the cookie when user logs out on site A or B? and so on and so forth?